# Python deepcopy of list on assignment

Tags: python, list, deep-copy, metaclass

Got this exercise on a python exam.
Trying to return a deep o copy of a list like this:

```
l = list()
l = [0,1,2]
l1 = l
l[0] = 1
```

l1 should contain `[0,1,2]` not `[1,1,2]`

The exercise specified to implement it by using a metaclass.

```
class deep(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict):
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict)
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super(deep, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwds)            
class list(metaclass=deep):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

From what i know , the `'='` in python is a statement and not an operator and it can't be overriden. Any idea on how to return a deep copy on assignment? Have been trying quite a lot but with no success.

Comment: In short, you cannot. And even if some ingenious hacker finds a way, it should **never** be used. And I'm not making blanket statements like that easily, believe me.

Comment: This is quite a strange exercise, given that you can perform a deep copy with only three characters using slice notation (`l1 = l[:]`). Using metaclasses feels overkill here.

Comment: If this is an exam question for school, I suggest you simply close it.  Asking us to help with your exam is the height of academic cheating.

Comment: @S.Lott: perhaps the exam is finished. At the very least though, it should be tagged `homework` or `exam`.

Comment: On the outlook of it, it seems as it is meant to implement a transparent replacement to the standard list-class, to add an automatic deep-copy on `__repr__` behaviour to lists. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Frederic Hamidi: maybe in your python version you can do a deepcopy thatway, most othes need to `from copy import deepcopy` and `b=deepcpy(a)` else only the main list gets copied, while all nested container-classes are kept as references in the new list! You may check that with e.g.: `for l in (a,b): id(l); map (id,l)`

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. @ninjagecko yeah the exam is finished a couple of days ago, have been trying to do this just for learning.

Comment: @Don, yup, I'm aware of that, maybe I shouldn't have used `deep` alone in this context. That said, the list in the question is only one level "deep", so a slice copy would work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, this is not possible in python without using some kind of extra syntax. As you said, you can't override `=`.

Comment: but he might use the `__repr__` method to achieve similar results! just don't return a string but a new class!

Comment: @DonQuestion: Is `__repr__` called on binding a name? That seems strange.

Comment: @Daenyth It is not. Don Question is off track.

Comment: @DonQuestion i tried using __repr__ too, by returning copy.deepcopy(self), but python returns: TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type list), because it's expects only strings by __repr__ i think

Comment: I didn't mean `repr()` but the  special method `__repr__` with two underscores. Nevertheless delnan is right, because it doesn't seem you could copy that way. I didn't test it out before, so i was off track. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

To understand what `l1 = l` does in Python read [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

To change what `l[0] = 1` does you could override `l`'s `__setitem__()` method:

```
>>> class L(list):
...     def __setitem__(self, i, v):
...         list.__setitem__(self, i, 10)
... 
>>> l = L()
>>> l.append(1)
>>> l
[1]
>>> l[0] = 0
>>> l
[10]
```

To change what `l = List(); l = [0,1,2]` does you could define `List.__del__()` method in CPython and manipulate the namespace `l` belongs to e.g., using `inspect` module. Needless to say you should never do that.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class L:
...     def __del__(self):
...         inspect.currentframe().f_globals['l'] = [1,2,3]
... 
>>> l = L()
>>> l = [0]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
```